# angularjs bootstrap datepicker is not updating the model

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to use the bootstrap datepicker using angular ui inside a my own angular controller.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

With all the libraries updated to the latest version I have a strange bevavior: the intial value is read from the controller, the datepicker is shown, I select the date and the textbox is updated but after this the value in the controller changes to undefined.
  I'm missing something? What can cause this behavior?

thanks,
  Luca morelli

this is the content of the view, two dates to define a range

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{dtFormat}}" ng-model="dtFine" is-open="dtFineOpened"
      ng-required="true" close-text="Chiudi" />
   <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openDtFine($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
   </span>
```

this is the typescript code that handles the involved members

```
        $scope.dtInizio = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY");
        $scope.dtFine = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY");
        $scope.dtInizioOpened = false;
        $scope.dtFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        $scope.openDtInizio = ($event) => {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

            $scope.dtInizioOpened = true;
        }
        $scope.openDtFine = ($event) => {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

            $scope.dtFineOpened = true;
        }
```

Using batarang I see that choosing the first date, when the popup is closed the model isn't update, when I go to open the second popup the modul is updated showing DtInizio as undefined

Debugging more I found this: I set a breakpoint to evalutate the status and I see that the value is
Tue Sep 16 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Eu...
and this is correct, but below I find
**proto**: Invalid Date

What does it means?

Comment: Try this: change the `$scope.dtFine = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY");` initialisation to `$scope.dt = { fine: moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY") };` and then on the HTML change `ng-model="dtFine"` to `ng-model="dt.fine"`.

Comment: I just found this:
Debugging more I found this: I set a breakpoint to evalutate the status and I see that the value is
Tue Sep 16 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Eu...
and this is correct, but below I find
proto: Invalid Date